# Pulling photos off an iPad

Tags: windows, macos, file-transfer, ipad

I don't work with or use Mac OS X as I am a Windows/Linux guy. But if I wanted to pull photos off of an iPad with my Windows laptop for someone, how would I do it?

Is it as simple and connecting to it from a USB cable or will it be more complex, because it is a Mac?

All I want to do is pull a select set of photos. I don't need everything. Just want to grab a few photos. Do I have to use itunes and stuff or will Windows recognize the device with a USB cable connection?

Comment: I just normally use iTunes to transfer the photos of my iPhone.  You pull everything then delete what you don't want.

Answer (score 3):

Reproducing steps from the [apple website](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4083) with the recommended procedure which may be what you are looking for.

To copy the photos to your computer using Windows Explorer:

1. Connect the iOS device to the computer.
2. Choose Start > Computer.
3. Double-click the logo for the device to browse its camera folders.
4. Navigate to [iOS device]\Internal Storage\DCIM\100APPLE.
5. Manually copy the content in this folder to your computer, wherever you would
   like to store it. Disconnect your device.

Let us know how it goes for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use itunes to sync your photos. f-spot for linux.  I believe with my iphone I can just open the folder under explorer and drill down and pull my pics off.

Answer (score 1):

If there are only a few photos, the easiest method of transferring them is by using a wifi photo transferring app. An example of this is: [Documents 2 FREE](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/documents-2-free-files-editor/id314894105?mt=8). The app works great!

All you'll have to do is put your photos that you want to be transferred on the app, turn on the WiFi transfer feature, and go to the stated URL on your computer's browser. The app opens a port of your iPad to the Local Area Network (not the public web), so your files stay as secure as your current WiFi hotspot.

I find this method *much* easier than syncing every time I want a few of my photos.

Comment: I had put the link there—in general, when pointing to software, in the future please always include a reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it as simple and connecting to it from a USB cable

It is as simple as using the USB, for Windows. Connect the two, Autoplay will pop up and then import images. Or open the device (iPad) when connected, select images and move (copy or cut) to where you want them.

I am not sure about Linux process as I am a Windows user. But, your tag for OS is Windows...so.